# Istio Envoy Rate Limit does not work for descriptors with sub path

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, rate-limiting

Trying to implement rate-limiting by using Istio EnvoyFilter.
Service level rate limiting works fine. But failed to configure rate limiting for any of the subpaths of my service. For instance '/productpage' and '/api/v1/products' still share service-level rate limiting.

Below is the Istio EnvoyFilter configuration with the Istio demo project Bookinfo, please let me know if any problem with the configuration.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: filter-local-ratelimit-svc
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: productpage
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.filters.http.local_ratelimit
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/udpa.type.v1.TypedStruct
            type_url: type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.local_ratelimit.v3.LocalRateLimit
            value:
              stat_prefix: http_local_rate_limiter

    - applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: "inbound|http|9080"
            route:
              action: ANY
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          typed_per_filter_config:
            envoy.filters.http.local_ratelimit:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/udpa.type.v1.TypedStruct
              type_url: type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.local_ratelimit.v3.LocalRateLimit
              value:
                rate_limits:
                  - actions:
                      - request_headers:
                          header_name: ":path"
                          descriptor_key: path
                stat_prefix: http_local_rate_limiter
                token_bucket:
                  max_tokens: 5
                  tokens_per_fill: 5
                  fill_interval: 60s
                filter_enabled:
                  runtime_key: local_rate_limit_enabled
                  default_value:
                    numerator: 100
                    denominator: HUNDRED
                filter_enforced:
                  runtime_key: local_rate_limit_enforced
                  default_value:
                    numerator: 100
                    denominator: HUNDRED
                response_headers_to_add:
                  - append: false
                    header:
                      key: x-local-rate-limit
                      value: "true" 
                descriptors:
                  - entries:
                      - key: path
                        value: /productpage
                    token_bucket:
                      max_tokens: 3
                      tokens_per_fill: 3
                      fill_interval: 60s
                  - entries:
                      - key: path
                        value: /api/v1/products
                    token_bucket:
                      max_tokens: 2
                      tokens_per_fill: 2
                      fill_interval: 60s
```

Resolved by move rate limit action as below:

```
- applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: "inbound|http|9080"
            route:
              action: ANY
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          route:
              rate_limits:
              - actions:
                - request_headers:
                    header_name: ":path"
                    descriptor_key: path
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved this by moving the rate limit action as below:

```
- applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: "inbound|http|9080"
            route:
              action: ANY
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          route:
              rate_limits:
              - actions:
                - request_headers:
                    header_name: ":path"
                    descriptor_key: path
```